# Hadoop Not Getting Started

Tags: hadoop-2.7.2

```
hduser@manoj-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-all.sh    
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
    Starting namenodes on [localhost]
    localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp’: Permission denied
    localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-manoj-VirtualBox.out
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 165: /tmp/hadoop-hduser-namenode.pid: No such file or directory
    localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp’: Permission denied
    localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-manoj-VirtualBox.out
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 165: /tmp/hadoop-hduser-datanode.pid: No such file or directory
    Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
    0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp’: Permission denied
    0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-manoj-VirtualBox.out
    0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 165: /tmp/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode.pid: No such file or directory
    starting yarn daemons
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp’: Permission denied
    starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-manoj-VirtualBox.out
    /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 125: /tmp/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager.pid: No such file or directory
    localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp’: Permission denied
    localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-manoj-VirtualBox.out
    localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 125: /tmp/yarn-hduser-nodemanager.pid: No such file or directory
```

I tried running

sudo chown -R hduser /usr/local/hadoop/

to give permissions to hduser. but still the same.

Also tried running **sbin/start-dfs.sh & sbin/start-yarn.sh** these also resulting same permisssion problems.

After Adding to sudoers some other permission denied errors are coming.

```
hduser@manoj-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-manoj-VirtualBox.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 165: /tmp/hadoop-hduser-namenode.pid: Permission denied
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-manoj-VirtualBox.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 165: /tmp/hadoop-hduser-datanode.pid: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-manoj-VirtualBox.out
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 165: /tmp/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode.pid: Permission denied
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-manoj-VirtualBox.out
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 125: /tmp/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager.pid: Permission denied
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-manoj-VirtualBox.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 125: /tmp/yarn-hduser-nodemanager.pid: Permission denied
```

Comment: You probably need to add hduser to sudoers

Comment: Hi Sarid after adding to sudoers some other permission denied errors are coming..please check i posted those in the question.

Comment: Did you run hadoop namenode -format?